# Why the products search bar is not working? Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, search, product, searchbar

I have a simple search bar to find products by name and order the results alphabetical.

-----> products_controller.rb

```
  def index
    scope = Product
    if params[:search]
      scope = scope.search(params[:search])
    end
    if params[:ordering] && ordering = ORDERS[params[:ordering].to_i]
      scope = scope.order(ordering)
    end
    @products = Product.includes(:current_price).all.stock.order('id DESC')
    @product_detail = ProductDetail.new
  end
```

-----> product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :product_details
    has_many :prices
    has_one :current_price, -> {
    where('prices.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM prices p2 WHERE product_id = prices.product_id)') 
  }, class_name: 'Price'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :prices 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_details

  # It returns the products whose names contain one or more words that form the query
  def self.search(query)
    where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"])
  end

  # Returns a count with the available products on stock
  def self.stock()
    select('products.*, SUM(case when product_statuses.available=true then 1 else 0 end) as count')
    .joins('LEFT JOIN `product_details` `product_details` ON `product_details`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`')
    .joins('LEFT JOIN `product_statuses` ON `product_statuses`.`id` = `product_details`.`status`')
    .group('products.id')
  end

end
```

I don't know, I have a very similar code for my Customers controller and model to do a phonebook and It works.

The only different is the "stock" to calculate how many units are available on the inventory, and It's working good.

I really need help with search bar :( I already reviewed all my code and looks good.

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is your `@product` variable not using the `scope` you already defined. I think it should be `@products = scope.includes(:current_price).all.stock.order('products.id DESC')`

Add `products.id` DESC instead of `id DESC` since the statement may be ambiguous to ActiveRecord. Also you will have to append products. to your orderng params.

Comment: I used your first suggestion and I receive the following error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Products#index

Comment: About your second suggestion, I dont want a case sensitive search

Comment: I have updated the answer. I guess you need to add `products.id DESC` instead of `id DESC` since the statement may be ambiguous to ActiveRecord. Also you will have to append `products.` to your orderng params.

Comment: Ok I use for solution ---> @products = scope.includes(:current_price).all.stock.order('id DESC') //////// But I getting "Column 'name' in where clause is ambiguous" error for this query: SELECT products.*, SUM(case when product_statuses.available=true then 1 else 0 end) as count FROM `products` LEFT JOIN `product_details` `product_details` ON `product_details`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` LEFT JOIN `product_statuses` ON `product_statuses`.`id` = `product_details`.`status` WHERE (name LIKE '%corneta%') GROUP BY products.id  ORDER BY id DESC

Comment: Solved, I changed the search model to: where(["products.name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"])

Comment: Correct! Sorry forget to mention  that.